# Controller View Getting wrong position

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I have application with Objective C which is developed for ios9 devices, when am trying to run the same code in xcode 8 am getting wrong position of my navigation bar,

Am using viewcontroller as a XIB and am converting into navigation controller in appdelegate class. is any one met this issue

[image]

Comment: I think this is the problem with constraint or auto layout. @Manoj Kumar

Comment: check your .plist Launch screen interface file base name key is there or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution:

- Select your Xib file of viewController.
- On the right side, navigate to the File Inspector tab.
- Change the value for "Build for" to "iOS 7.0 and Later" or any other iOS version and later.
- Clean, Rebuild and Run project.

  [image: img]